# Painting pixels in Jython

Tags: java, swing, awt, jython

My aim is to create a simple wrapper for painting arbitrary pixels to a window.

Unfortunately I always get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    canvas = window( 'Test', WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
  File "..\painter.py", line 16, in __init__
    my_jframe.getContentPane().add( my_image)
TypeError: add(): 1st arg can't be coerced to java.awt.Component, java.awt.PopupMenu
```

What's the problem???

Thank you for your suggestions!

Lucas.

As caller I use the following:

```
# (test.py)
#! /usr/bin/env jython

import time
import random

from painter import window

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

canvas = window( 'Test', WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
print( 'fuck1')

for x in range( WINDOW_WIDTH):
    for y in range ( WINDOW_HEIGHT):
        rgba = [ random.randint( 0, 255), random.randint( 0, 255), random.randint( 0, 255), 255]
        print( x, y, rgba)
        canvas.paint_pixel( x, y, rgba)
        time.sleep( 1)
```

The called module looks like this:

```
# (painter.py)
#! /usr/bin/env jython

import javax.swing
import java.awt

class window( object):

    def __init__( self, window_title, window_width, window_height):
        my_jframe = javax.swing.JFrame( window_title)

        my_image = java.awt.image.BufferedImage( 
            window_width,
            window_height,
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
            )
        my_jframe.getContentPane().add( my_image)

        my_jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation( javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        my_jframe.setSize( window_width, window_height)
        my_jframe.setLocationRelativeTo( None)                                # center window
        my_jframe.show()

    def paint_pixel( self, x, y, rgba):
        c = java.awt.Color( rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3])
        self.my_image.setRGB( x, y, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Swing does not allow changing a `BufferedImage` on the fly, but you could use something like this:

Modified version of your `test.py`:

```
# (test2.py)
#! /usr/bin/env jython

import time
import random

from painter2 import window
from java.awt import Color
from java.util import Random

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

canvas = window( 'Test', WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

randomNumbers = Random(123456)

for x in range( WINDOW_WIDTH):
    for y in range ( WINDOW_HEIGHT):
        color = Color(randomNumbers.nextInt(2 ** 24))
        #print( x, y, color)
        canvas.add_pixel( x, y, color)
        #time.sleep( 1)

canvas.repaint()
```

Modified version of your `painter.py`:

```
# (painter2.py)
#! /usr/bin/env jython

import javax.swing
import java.awt

from colored_pixel import colored_pixel

class window( javax.swing.JPanel):

    def __init__( self, window_title, window_width, window_height):
        my_jframe = javax.swing.JFrame( window_title)

        my_jframe.getContentPane().add( self, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER)

        self.pixels = []

        my_jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation( javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        my_jframe.setSize( window_width, window_height)
        my_jframe.setLocationRelativeTo( None)    # center window
        my_jframe.setVisible( True)

        print self.getWidth()
        print self.getHeight()

    def add_pixel( self, x, y, color):
        self.pixels.append( colored_pixel( x, y, color))

    def paintComponent( self, graphics):
        for pixel in self.pixels:
            graphics.setColor( pixel.color)
            graphics.drawRect( pixel.x, pixel.y, 1, 1)
```

Small class to store pixel location and color:

```
class colored_pixel( object):
    def __init__( self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
```